# Can I use the argparse help string to decribe my script's return values?

Tags: python, argparse, docstring

I know I can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#description)'s help string to describe both the general purpose of my script, and its input arguments. Is there also a built-in / conventional method with which I can describe my script's return values?

Comment: Do you suppose that user won't understand why he's trying to launch you script? Anyway, there's `description` argument in constructor which usually used as app description (surprisingly).

Comment: There's also an `epilog` parameter.  You might also want to use the `RawDescriptionFormater` (see the docs for correct name) to preserve newline formatting.  The content of these parameters is entirely up to you.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, my intention is not to clarify the script purpose - which I do, indeed, in the description - but to provide more details on the structure of the return values. Does that make things clearer?

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion: there isn't a dedicated argument; After scouring the internet, nothing came up. Using the epilog/description is probably your best option.